# MediaComposition.Add of a BackgroundAudioTrack - can I fully preserve its quality?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have this code:

```
var composition = new MediaComposition();
composition.Clips.Add(clip);

var mp3 = await this.music_file();
if (mp3 != "") {
    var music_file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(mp3);
    var music = await BackgroundAudioTrack.CreateFromFileAsync(music_file);
    music.TrimTimeFromStart = TimeSpan.Zero;
    music.TrimTimeFromEnd = TimeSpan.Zero;
    composition.BackgroundAudioTracks.Add(music);
}
```

The problem is that in the final .mp4, quite a bit of the audio quality is lost. My .mp3 contains a lot of sound effects very close to each other. My mp3 sounds perfect, but when added to the video, the final video is quite worse in audio quality.

Is there a way to fully preserve the audio quality of the original audio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> MediaComposition.Add of a BackgroundAudioTrack - can I fully preserve its quality?

Derive from my testing, the audio track sounds like good, and currently there is no such api could set the quality for the background audio track.

And the only way is pass specific [`MediaEncodingProfile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.mediaproperties.mediaencodingprofile?view=winrt-20348) `mediaComposition.RenderToFileAsync`, and you could set the audio quality base on requirement.

For example

```
MediaEncodingProfile encodingProfile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp4(VideoEncodingQuality.HD720p); //default audio  aac 48000 2 19200

//encodingProfile.Audio = AudioEncodingProperties.CreateAac(48000, 2, 19200);

var saveOperation = mediaComposition.RenderToFileAsync(file, MediaTrimmingPreference.Fast,encodingProfile);
```

Comment: Thanks, I will do some testing and get back to you.

Comment: Hi Nico, sorry for the delay. It took me a bit to reintegrate and re-run my tests. So far, it seems to be preserving the original sound quality, which is great! I will drop another comment if in the future I'm still having problems with this.